# Adding custom designed product to cart in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

Hi I am developing a site for T-shirt designing. I have a custom UI where all the T-shirt products in my site are loaded. customer can design the T-shirt according to their needs like changing color,adding text/image etc using my UI. At the end of UI I have a buy button where user can buy the custom product. How can I add this product to my Drupal cart when user clicks buy button? I have the product id and price loaded in my hand and am using Drupal commerce module in my site.

This is my button form

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="button">
                                Buy Now! </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can done it using [commerce_cart_product_add()](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_product_add/DC). Pass product id and line item as parameters. For details please check [here](http://www.drupal.org/node/1288414).Hope this will help you..